# копирование только уникальных данных в sql

Tags: mysql

есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `a` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `b` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `c` int(9) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `num` (`num`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3637377 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

и

```
CREATE TABLE `T2` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `a` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `b` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `c` int(9) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `num` (`num`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3637377 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

надо вставить из одной таблицы в другую только те данные которых нет в другой. можете помочь?

Comment: А по какому критерию Вы определяете отсутствие записи во второй таблице? По `id` или еще что-то учитывать нужно? Просто вот здесь https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp есть общее представление решения вашей задачи. Посмотрите.

Comment: и к тому же `UNIQUE KEY num (num)` Вы создаете ключ по несуществующему полю

Comment: c и num это одна и таже колонка (моя опечатка), UNIQUE KEY num (num) это для того чтоб в этой колонке не повторялись данные

Answer (score 0):

Если идентифицировать записи только по `id` то как-то так:

```sql
insert into T2 (select T1.* from T1 join T2 on T1.id <> T2.id)
```

Comment: помогло  INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT

Comment: @maloi, Не ну если Васварнинги не парят, то можно и так